# Bucles anidados. While, for e if

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola buenas tengo una duda, tengo esto:

```
cont = 0
    while 1:
        recibe un mensaje (es un cliente, por lo que uso un while true)
        for a in mensaje recibido:
            if a ... :
                     ................
            else:
                      ....................
                cont +=1
```

Mi duda es al tener estos bucles anidados no realiza correctamente lo que esta en el if, y mi duda surge porque no sé como se ejecuta eso. Hace una vez el while, despues hace una iteracion del for y ejecuta el if-else? Lo que quiero es que cuando haya realizado el for (reocrre el mensaje) salga (pero no se si ya ha termiando de recibir el mensaje). ¿Podríais explicarme como van estos bucles anidados? ¿Estaría bien lo que comenté?

Comment: Es como comentas, por cada iteración del `while` el `for` itera hasta terminar de recorrer el mensaje, por cada iteración del `for` se ejecuta el `if` o el `else` si el `if` no se cumple. Cuando el `for` se termina el `while` vuelve a iterar de nuevo, se obtiene un nuevo mensaje y el `for` itera sobre el  y así indefinidamente. No termino de entender cual es tu problema exactamente.

Comment: @FJSevilla pero si quiero que cuando haya leido todo, deberia poner un break el final del while ¿no? O al final del for?, lo que quisiera saber es si ese break se realizaría al finalizar el for ¿?

Comment: ¿La idea entonces es que vas recibiendo mensajes y cuando no queden más salir del while? Si es esto, ¿cómo sabes que ya no quedan más mensajes?

Comment: @FJSevilla Si es eso, no lo sabes, porque eres un cliente, recibes información, manipulas esa información y después envias un mensaje al servidor. La verdad es complicado de explicar, me gustaria poder hablar por privado pero no se puede (así creo que lo entenderías).

Comment: Si el servidor no envía ninguna señal de que no va a enviar nada más o no es deducible del contenido del propio mensaje lo único que te quedaría es establecer un tiempo de espera máximo por ejemplo y salir cuando se cumpla. La implementación ya dependería de como interactúes con el servidor y la tecnología usada para la comunicación...

Comment: Quizás sería más adecuado que ampliaras tu pregunta con más datos de como recibes ese mensaje o desde donde. Es posible que exista una solución ya creada de alguna de las librerias standard de python que te permita hacer polling o a lo mejor sugerirte una manera distinta de resolver tu pregunta a la que tu propones. Por lo demás coincido con FJSevilla

Comment: @FJSevilla Al hacer un bucle for y dentro un if, si quiero guardar el valor de la anterior posicion del mensaje del for junto al valor acyual, se podría?? ¿Cómo posdría hacerlo? for i in lista: a = (valor de la posicion anterior en la lista) if se cumple a e i se hace esto (print(i) break)

Comment: ¿Lo que buscarías sería guardar el valor de i de la iteración anterior o el índice de ese valor?

Comment: @FJSevilla El valor de la i en la iteracion anterior, por ejemplo supongamos que tengo un array (string)  "x c vced sdf ewer as u", antes de la u hay un espacio en blanco, pues quiero hacer un if con la posicion anterior y la actual (la anterior en este caso es un espacio en blanco, y la actual es la u)

Comment: Auenque hay varias formas de hacerlo lo más simple es que uses una vaiable declarada fuera del for y en cada iteración, al final le asignas el valor actual de i. De esta forma en la siguinte contendrá el valor de i de la iteración anterior. Otra posibilidad es usar dos iteradores y zip, desplazando una posición antes del for con next(). Si no te aclaras, puedes plantear una nueva pregunta, por comentarios es muy dificil responder con código por la limitación de espacio y la perdida de formato.

Comment: @FJSevilla Creo que ya te entiendo, gracias. :) Un placer hablar contigo FJSevilla

Comment: @FJSevilla Una duda que me surge es por ejemplo, estoy en un for i in mensaje: tengo un if (): else: mensaje += algo, que es lo que debería poner para que se concatene el mensaje y empiece desde el principio a recorrerlo, pero esta vez el mensaje ya ha sido concatenado ¿?